# Send Notification from a non-activity class

Tags: android, notifications

I am using a service which fires notification to the users device when there happens a particular in the backend. But now this time at the time of login ( a successful piece of code runs) in a non-activity class. How can I send the notifications in that case from a  non-activity class???

code:

```
public XMPPConnection checkXMPPConnection(String userName,String password) {

        connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

        try {
            connection.connect();
            System.out.println("Logginnnngggg innn");

            connection.login(userName, password);

            PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.chat);
            final PacketCollector collector = connection.createPacketCollector(filter);
            connection.addPacketListener(new PacketListener() {

                @Override
                public void processPacket(Packet packet) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    //notification(packet.getFrom());
                    packet = collector.nextResult();
                    Message message = (Message)packet;
                    notification(""+message.getBody(), 0);

                    System.out.println("Messageeeee isisssssss......."+message.getBody());               

                }

            }, filter);
```

Notification code:

```
public void notification(CharSequence message, int notificationID) {

        String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)UserMenuActivity.context.getSystemService(ns);
        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        CharSequence tickerText = message;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);



        CharSequence contentTitle = "ABC";
        CharSequence contentText = message;


        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.ledARGB = 0xff00ff00;
        notification.ledOnMS = 300;
        notification.ledOffMS = 1000;
        mNotificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);

    }
```

BOTH OF THE ABOVE METHODS ARE IN A NON-ACTIVITY CLASS.

this method is in non-activity class. I just want to send the notifications when the above code is triggered now tell me about the same how can I ??

Thanks

Comment: Absolutely unclear. Explain better and provide code, commented to make us understand what you want to do.

Comment: @Snicolas code added. Please have a look

Answer (score 1):

There could be several options :

- adding a parameter to your `checkXMPP` method : the paramater would be a context. This usually is the simplest but leads to a lot of code tied to a context, thus more coupling. Indeed, here you would need the packet listener to be given a context.
- you can also start an [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) of your own that will update the Notification via the NotificationManager. Start the service using an Intent. That can look difficult but actually it is not.

Here is an example : http://androidhotel.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/a-simple-notification-system-with-the-intentservice-part-i/

Comment: @Sincolas. Please try to understand I am already using a service in the background in which I have written the notification code. Only in one case ( at the time of login ) I have to check it in the above class and have to trigger a notification. What can I do now?

Comment: What is your problem exactly ? Can't you use the NotificationManager and a Notification.Builder ?

Comment: I think we cannot use them in a non-activity class

Comment: Nope, a service can use the NotificationManager service.

Answer (score 0):

Here is How I did this,
create a `NotificationProvider.java` class like this

```
public class NotificationProvider {

public NotificationProvider() {
}

public void setNotification(Context context, String notificationTitle, String notificationMessage, int notificationRequestCode){
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_mother_and_child_care)
                    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                    .setColor(101)
                    .setContentText(notificationMessage);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DashboardActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, notificationRequestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

}

and call `setNotification()` function in any `activity.class` like this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private NotificationProvider notificationProvider;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    notificationProvider = new NotificationProvider();
    notificationProvider.setNotification(this, "Title", "Message", 1);
}
```